# Asyncronous module function is not working

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and am facing an issue with await/async functions. This are my files:

**main.js**

```
var fd = require('fdmodule');
let r = await fd.matches();
console.log('r: ' + r);
```

**fdmodule.js**

```
const baseUrl = 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/';
const token = '*********';
const https = require('https');

exports.matches = async function () { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {   
        let x = await callUrl(baseUrl + 'matches');
        console.log('x: ' + x);
        resolve(x);
    });
};

async function callUrl(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var req = require('request');
        var header = { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': token } };
        req(url, header, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is my output:

```
let r = await fd.matches();
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

When I remove the `await` of this line and change my function to

```
exports.matches = function () {     
    let x = await callUrl(baseUrl + 'matches');
    console.log('x: ' + x);
    return x;    
};
```

I get the `console.log('x: ' + x);` result, but only after the `console.log('r: ' + r);` which obviously is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right... so, that's impossible. One way or another, you'll have a promise to deal with if you use an async function in a non-async function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. Here are the files:

**main.js**

```
var fd = require('fdmodule');

loadMatches()

async function loadMatches() {    
    console.log('r: ' + await fd.matches());
}
```

**fdmodule.js**

```
const baseUrl = 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/';
const token = '*************';

exports.matches = async function () { 
    return await callUrl('matches');    
};

async function callUrl(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var req = require('request');
        var header = { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': token } };
        req(baseUrl + url, header, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, there is no point in doing `return await callUrl('matches');`  You can just do `return callUrl('matches');`.

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00. It also worked without the `await`.